# How can I determine which device a loop loops back to?

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu, disk

On my Ubuntu system I am running WUBI and thus I have a device: `/dev/loop0` which is actually a file on the NTFS filesystem of the main drive. I know that it is not necessarily the case that the loopback device points to a disk, but how do I figure out if it is and which disk it loops back to (in c/c++ ofc)?

As for why, I am doing some light profiling of the system and want to merge partitions on a loopback with the main disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I do not understand what "light profiling" has to do with merging partitions
or what you are really trying to accomplish but finding out which loop back device is
associated with which file can be done with the losetup command. The code to do this needs to be running as root for this so you would run  "sudo losetup -a".

To do this same trick yourself in C/C++ the procedure would be
Parse /proc/partions to find a loop device in use
open each loop device
fstat it to make sure it is a loop device
ioctl LOOP_GET_STATUS
ioctl LOOP_GET_STATUS64

All of the important information is in the header file linux/loop.h
If any of the above sounds too strange and/or vague just use losetup.

Comment: profiling, in my case: trying to figure out how much free space there is on each drive. since wubi makes a fs out of a file, the host filesystem reports it as used space even though it isnt.